# Plugin Wordpress para criar um contador de visitas (com texto)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Como posso colocar um contador de visitas em meu site `Wordpress` para que a cada acesso suba `+1` ?

> Tentei procurar por plugins, mas não achei nenhum que mostrasse somente o número de acessos em forma de texto, o que achei foi só o que conta as estatísticas, como IP, navegador, etc...

Comment: Pode mencionar os plugins que achou?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/who-hit-the-page-hit-counter/ - http://wordpress.org/plugins/free-counter/ - http://wordpress.org/plugins/counterize/ - entre outros...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei um script `PHP + TXT` para não haver necessidade de banco de dados.

> Link: http://www.codigofonte.net/scripts/php/contador/1352_jcr-contador-v1-0

Eu baixei o script e enviei para o diretório do tema, e dei `permissão 777` no arquivo `contador.txt`, para poder gravar os dados no arquivo `.txt`.

Depois fui no diretório do meu tema e editei o arquivo `header.php` e coloquei:

```
<?php include("contador/contador.php"); ?>
```

No lugar que queria que aparecesse.

#### Com esse script é possível:

- Mostrar as visitas de **hoje**
- Mostrar as visitas de **ontem**
- Mostrar o **total de visitas**
- Mostrar o **recorde** e **data de visitas**

---

> Problema resolvido!